# Webrtc - How to get bytes send and bytes receive count

Tags: webrtc

How could I get the bytes send amount and receive amount that shows as chrome?

I want to use the data to check the connection quality. Or are there any suggestion that I should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the getStats API. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/ shows an example.

Comment: could I ask a maybe silly question? I found [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-stats/issues/189) about the "inbound-rtp" and "outbound-rtp" remote or not. It seem that they already change it cause I didn't saw them in the [doc](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats/#inboundrtpstats-dict*). Buy when I use receiver.getStat() I saw the report still have **isRemote** property in *RTCInboundRTPVideoStream*. Why?

Comment: the spec and implementations don't match up. isRemote will go away in Firefox 65 actually: https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/getstats-isremote-65/